# Error with php heredoc

Tags: php, heredoc

I have a problem with php heredoc. I'm trying to do something like this.

```
$heredoc = <<<_HERE
This is the way
I try to use the
heredoc, but apparently
something is going wrong
_HERE;
```

Obviously I should get this:

```
This is the way
I try to use the
heredoc, but apparently
something is going wrong
```

But I get this:

This is the way I try to use the heredoc, but apparently something is going wrong

It's not formatted, and the main idea is to get formatted text.

Can someone help me please?

Comment: Browsers collapse white spaces.

Comment: if you are just `echo`'ing it out, enclose it in pre-tags like `echo "<pre>$heredoc</pre>";`

Comment: the end `_HERE` shouldn't contains space or tab infront of it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use pre tags :

```
$heredoc = <<<_HERE
<pre>
This is the way
I try to use the
heredoc, but apparently
something is going wrong
</pre>
_HERE;
```

Comment: Well... I thinks is good for me... Thank's. But actually heredoc should do it without the <pre> tag. That's my doubt, why it doesn't work.

Comment: @AndresOrozco if you output it to a normal text file, you'd be fine - heredocs are as-is, they don't do any HTML coding for you.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
<?php
    $heredoc = <<<_HERE
This is the way
I try to use the
heredoc, but apparently
something is going wrong
_HERE;

    echo "<pre>";
    echo $heredoc;
    echo "</pre>";
?>
```

Comment: What is with that use of `print_r`? :P

Comment: That's the longest way to output text you could possibly come up with after `echo`, `print`, `printf`... lol  And ok ^^  I was just pointing it out because using that to print a string is discouraged.